# Deform an array of objects without modifying its geometry, just the relative position of them

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to model a lipid bilayer and for the moment have managed to create the main structure (three arrays and one mirror).  The problem is that the overall shape is flat and I'm trying to make it irregular.  The shape of the undeformed array is like this

[image: flat lb]

My objective is to deform the array but without deforming the meshes like this

[image: lattice modified lb]

but keeping the spheres with the same shape.  Something like modifying only the relative location of the individual molecules.  Is there any way to do that?  I'm fairly new to blender and not familiar with all of the modeling techniques.

Thanks!

Comment: I vaguely recall a question from a week ago not very different from this that used a particle system emitting from vertices of a subdivided plane.  Maybe that can be adapted here.

Comment: I found it : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84815/how-do-i-make-an-ocean-of-independently-moving-objects

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier/68925#68925

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a "dummy" object to parent your array object to.

Here I've created a two dimensional array of planes and applied two ***Curve Modifiers***... one the for the X and one for the Y direction:

[image]

Once that's done, create one instance of your object and parent it to the plane array by going to Object Properties and selecting the plane.

Right Click on the plane and enable duplication with "Faces" as the method.  This will create an instance of the child (sphere) for every face of the plane array.  You can manipulate the curves under the plane to give you the desired bend.

[image]

---

---

***EDIT:*** An alternative would be to apply and separate the array elements and use the Proportional Editing Tool to position them:

1.) Apply the ***Array Modifiers***

2.) Go into ***Edit Mode*** and Select All by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> twice.

3.) Press <kbd>P</kbd> and separate by ***Loose Parts***

4.) Go back to ***Object Mode***, select all the new Objects, and set their origins to the center of the spheres: <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>

5.) Select the middle sphere and enable ***Proportional Editing*** in the toolbar.

6.) Translate the sphere in the Z-direction and use the scroll-wheel to adjust the size of the Proportional Translation.

[image]