# Orientation towards an other object with Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I've tried to follow the tutorial wrote by Ed Tate in this topic : [How to create a 3D virus envelope like this in image below?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97228/how-to-create-a-3d-virus-envelope-like-this-in-image-below)

But I can't achieve to have a correct rotation of the lipids :

[image]

The lipids are (theoretically) supposed to point to the center of the ico sphere. And it seems that they don't want to do it.

I don't really find what I'm doing wrong so if someone knows what is my mistake, I would be glad to learn which one it is.

.blend : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the outer icosphere's vertex normals, same as you have used their vertex locations, to make the lipids face the center. Simply replace the node connection to the loops normal list output from the current vector list to the vertex normals provided by the object mesh data node.

[image]

If you want to reverse the direction you can do this in the direction to rotation node you've already added:

[image]

Comment: Direction To Rotation Node is vectorized. The loop can be skipped.