# How to animate morphing a sphere from a lipid membrane (rectangular plane)

Tags: animation

I'm trying to animate cellular endocytosis, similar to in the link below. I wanted to show a virus particule moving towards a flat lipid membrane, before getting engulfed by the membrane and emerging on the other side surrounded by a lipid bubbble.I'm completely new to blender and I don't even know where to start, any pointers in the right direction would be extremely helpful!

https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgfycat.com%2Fdiscover%2Fendocytosis-gifs&psig=AOvVaw2F0LWhpRoofavpHTlUDfVS&ust=1591082936457000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCOCHq4GM4OkCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97228/how-to-create-a-3d-virus-envelope-like-this-in-image-below#98019

Answer (score 1):

Let say you want to achieve something like that:

[image]

What you should do is use *Metaballs* for the 2 cells, and a classical mesh for the virus. This way you can make the 2 metaballs merge together. You'll need to give a semi-transparent material to those cells (here a simplified version of what it could be):

[image]