# Apply array modifier on multiple objects that have modifiers themselves

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

I have a scene with a movie theatre and I modeled a chair.

The chair is composed of different parts (meshes) that have subdivision modifier applied to them.

[image]

I want to apply an array modifier on the chair in order to make a real movie theatre but I can only apply two array modifiers (for both directions) on each parts of my chair. For performance reasons, I want to keep the meshes without the subdivision modifier applied to them.

How can I do that?

Comment: If you have chair with Subsurf already applied (Apply button was pressed in modifier settings, modifier was removed from stack, changes to geometry became real) then there aren't really any choices except for retopology to bring polycount down or modeling new chair. That said if you're concerned about performance you could bake normal map and use lowpoly chair in the scene

Comment: [Array will eliminate any performance benefits](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143905/making-a-wall-made-from-glass-bricks/143920#143920) Use dupligroups or particles instead https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108541/animate-a-spheres-system-as-a-camera-diaphragm/108546#108546 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier/68925#68925

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/113973/place-spawn-objects-along-curve-with-randomized-scale-and-rotation/113989#113989 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84815/how-do-i-make-an-ocean-of-independently-moving-objects/84835#84835

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I finally managed to join all the parts then apply the subdivision surface modifier on the whole chair and then the two array modifiers. It's reducing a lot the amount of memory needed when rendering.